# pan/tilt - DJI SDK - OpenCV

Tags: windows, opencv, dji-sdk, drone.io

I am working on my master thesis to control gimbal of drone using parameters coming from openCV for image processing

is this possible through windows SDK to control pan and tilt angle of the gimbal as a real time control depend on the data coming from the image processing.

I would highly appreciate your answer cause I don't find much information about that in the internet

thank you

Comment: "windows SDK" means the SDK provided by microsoft for developing windows. it does not mean "DJI SDK". your question probably *not* specific to microsoft windows.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.